# Was Comic Book Guy correct about Green Lantern?

Tags: movie, dc, green-lantern, the-simpsons

In *The Simpsons Movie*, the following conversation occurs:

> Grampa Simpson: [in video] Twisted tail! A thousand eyes! Trapped forever!!! EPA!!! EPA!!!
>
> Marge: EPA? What could that be?
>
> Comic Book Guy: I believe it's the sound the Green Lantern made when Sinestro threw him into a vat of acid. E-P-A!
>
> Marge: Yeah. Thanks for coming over.

A later *Green Lantern* comic would reference this.

[image: Green Lantern - Simpsons reference]

Did any comics released before *The Simpsons Movie* include Green Lantern being thrown into a vat of acid by Sinestro and making an "EPA" noise, or any scenario similar to that?

Comment: All I know is the US Environmental protection agency (EPA) deals with things like acid in the environment? Not sure if that applies.

Comment: @RikerW - That was what it turned out to be in the movie, the joke was that Comic Book Guy would immediately pick some super-obscure and geeky comic book reference as the most obvious interpretation.

Comment: If I was a gambling man, I'd bet it was just a joke and the issue you mention is the only one in which that happens. I'm a gambling man, so I do bet that thing I just said.

Answer (score 2):

> Did any comics released before The Simpsons Movie include Green Lantern being thrown into a vat of acid by Sinestro and making an "EPA" noise, or any scenario similar to that?

The comic shown in your question appears to be Green Lantern Vol 4, #25. It hit stores in November 2007, with a cover date of 2008, [according to Comic Vine](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/green-lantern-25-sinestro-corps-war-part-11-birth-/4000-119950/).

The Simpsons Movie was released in July of 2007, at least 3 months prior.

According to [this random guy](http://www.ryan-sweeney.net/digitalscrapbook/2009/10/eepaa-green-lantern-25/), it may have been inspired by the film and not the other way around. Comic book resources also [supports](http://www.cbr.com/comic-book-easter-eggs-steranko-bad-robot-and-glepa/) this.

I could find no other reference to acid vats, Sinestro or GL in any works published before then, so I think it is safe to say that the comic did it after it was heard in the film and it made it into the film because Comic Book Guy is just that kind of character. Also note that GL isn't making the sound but it seems like it is coming from the explosion or Sinestro's energy blast.

Comment: Referenced here; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinestro_Corps_War#cite_ref-Artists_Two_21-1 but unfortunately the link is dead.